# How to Slowly Darken a Picture using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe

How do we slowly darken the picture as shown in the sample GIF?

[image: Gin vs Aizen]

I have a still image of a face made but I really don't have idea on how to achieve that effect in Photoshop.

Any hints would be very welcome.

Thank you all!